# Deriving decimal numbers in float input sometimes minus the value by 1

Tags: c, floating-point, decimal

I am trying to separate the numbers in a floating input (xx.yy) and extract them out.
Not so sure if this is the online compiler fault but for some reasons, there are times when I run my following code, the decimal places that I extract seemingly -1 in value.

I am using this online compiler (https://repl.it/languages/c).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int whole_num = 0;
    int dec_num = 0;

    float u_input = 0.0;
    printf("Input in a float: ");
    scanf("%f", &u_input);

    whole_num = (int) u_input;
    printf("1. Whole number is %d\n", whole_num);

    dec_num = (u_input - whole_num)*100;
    printf("2. Decimal number is %d\n", dec_num);

    return 0;

}
```

For example, there are times when I input in 99.95, instead of expecting `95` for my `dec_num`, it gave me `94`. Then again, if I used another input such as `123.95` it returns me `95` instead. And as a result, if my code is giving me the -1 result, it will fails in other parts of my code.Decimal

I can't find out if it is an error with the way I have written my code and/ or if it is an issue with the compiler (also tried it with other online compilers which seemingly giving me similar results)

Can anyone share any insights to me on this? Or if there is a proper method that I will get the decimal number I expected without the -1?

Comment: You're experiencing floating point inexact effects.  You probably need to apply some rounding to your calculations.

Comment: @TomKarzes without the use of `#include <math.h>` or `round`, I guess I am unable to derive the expected result that I wanted based on my above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating point numbers are represented using binary notation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

As such, decimal numbers that do not have an exact binary representation are stored as an approximation to the desired values.

For example, a value like `1.25` has an exact binary representation (5*(2^-2)), while numbers like `1.3` do not and need to be apprximated.

This [website](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) offers a good visualization of this phenomenon.